# Magnolia CMS OpenSocial Container

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia, opensocial

I wanted to use Magnolia CMS module OpenSocial Container for gadgets written on GWT. I've tried to run it locally but without success, even default gadgets are not rendering as they described on demo(http://dlipp.blogspot.com/2011/03/magnolia-module-opensocial-container-is.html). I were not able to find any docs to resolve my issue, nor got answer from magnolia forum. If there any use case of Magnolia OpenSocial Container? Or any other CMS as gadget container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include any details on what isn't working, but Daniel's post references the doc page on the wiki:

http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Magnolia+OpenSocial+Container

One thing that looks like it might trip folks up is the fact that ContextRoot is hardcoded to **/magnolia-opensocial-sample-webapp**. Are you deploying with that context?

Hope one of those things helps.

Comment: Thanks, It helps. It turns out that I've skipped this step and deployed magnolia in different context :(.

Answer (score -2):

Nuxeo (http://www.nuxeo.com) is a content management platform that provides a gadget container.
Just in case.

Note:
Roland is [VP Product & Marketing](http://www.nuxeo.com/en/about/management-team) of Nuxeo

Comment: Please also disclose your affiliation with this product in your answer.

Comment: @Roland It's not about hiding it. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) clearly states "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers"